# How to format beanio in Java?

Tags: java, xml, bean-io

Wasn't sure how to better describe the problem in the title, but basically I have a beanio XML where one of the fields is this:

```
<field name="number" length="19" padding="0" justify="right"/>
```

My issue is that the value that goes here can be negative or positive, but I need the positive or negative sign to be at the front while the number itself is in the back.

For example, I am currently getting:

```
0000000000000-10500
```

However, what I need is:

```
-000000000000010500
```

Is there a way to edit the field so that it comes out with the negative/positive sign in front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: This is not tested

You can try:

```
<field name="number" length="19" padding="0" justify="right" format="-#0"/>
```

OR

```
<field name="number" length="19" padding="0" justify="right" format="#0;-#0"/>
```

OR if that fails:

```
<field name="number" length="19" padding="0" justify="right" format="##################0;-##################0"/>
```

18 x '#' and 1 x '0'

OR

```
<field name="number" length="19" padding="0" justify="right" format="0000000000000000000;-0000000000000000000"/>
```

19 x '0'.

See the [Reference Guide](https://beanio.github.io/docs/reference-guide#a12-field) and just google how to use the decimal format pattern for the `java.lang.Number` field - [DecimalFormat API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

Comment: I got it working with the last example you showed. Would you know how to do the same thing if the number was a String data type? Currently trying to research how online but haven't seen anything relevant.

Comment: @CrisManrique it should actually be a new question, although related. You could do it with a custom `TypeHandler` that does the formatting.